# Trying to ssh into the router and getting the output but its throwing error that the file path is not valid

Tags: python, file, ssh, router

I am new to Python and is using Python 3.7. I wrote a code to ssh into multiple routers and get the output from them. But while executing the code its throwing the error that the file path is not valid.

I tried to put the directory which I am using in the code and was able to access the file. In the error its adding extra '\' and is saying path is incorrect.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import os
import sys
import time
import select
import paramiko
import re

fd = open('C:\Test.txt','w')
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = fd
platform = 'cisco_ios'
username = 'cisco'
password = 'cisco'
ip_add_file = open('C:\IPAddressList.txt','r')

for host in ip_add_file:
    #host = host.strip()
    device = ConnectHandler(device_type=platform, ip=host, username=username, password=password)
    output = device.send_command('sh ver | i upt')
    print(output)

fd.close()
```

IPAddressList.txt is the file which contains the list of the IPs 
Test.txt is the file where I want the output.

Comment: I suggest you use os.path tools to have more OS independent program. It may also fix your problem. os.path.join('c:', 'Test.txt'). Also you can use os.path to check for file existence and other things https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: I tried to change it but its still throwing the same error. When I am trying to put the path as "os.path.join('c:', 'Test.txt')" it says [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C: test.txt' and when I am trying with"os.path.join('c:', 'Test.txt')" [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test.txt'

Comment: I just came to know about the raw strings in Python. I tried to add 'r' in front of the file name but still no luck

Comment: os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'Test.txt')

Comment: Its the same error again. this is what I did
x=os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'iplist.txt')
ip_add_file = open(x,'r')

Here is the error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\iplist.txt'

Comment: Here is the thing if I go ahead and print os.path.join() or try the raw string or try os sep its printing the correct path but when I am trying to execute on my code its throwing the invalid path error